# How to start a user script from a sql trigger

Tags: sql, database, triggers, informix

I'm not sure if it is possible. I have an informix database, and I would need to start a bash script from a database trigger. In the [informix documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls487.htm) explains how to start a user procedure, but it has to be an stored procedure; i would like to start a user program available in the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't want to do it - because running the program will be slow - but if you decide you still want to do it, then you will have the trigger run a stored procedure, and the stored procedure will use the SYSTEM statement to execute the bash script.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE trivial(c varchar(30) default "hello world")
    DEFINE cmd VARCHAR(60);
    LET cmd = "echo " || c || " >/tmp/hello.world 2>&1";
    SYSTEM cmd;
END PROCEDURE
```

Note that the script won't have a terminal for standard input or standard output or standard error (offhand, I think it gets `/dev/null`).  Also note that the command I showed is fraught with permissions issues - the second user running the procedure is likely to get permission errors on the file.  You also need to be wary of 'Unix injection attacks' - the code shown takes a string provided by the invoker of the script, and runs it.  If the string contain back-quotes or ... then the user can execute the commands.  It may not do them much good to run a command as themselves, but be leery of what I just showed.

If the script exits with a non-zero status, your stored procedure will fail with error -668 and an ISAM error corresponding to the exit status.